# Product name only appears in upper case letters

Tags: product

Having an issue where all my product names are appearing in only uppercase letters on our website while in Magento, the product names only have the first letter of each word capitalized.

Comment: When viewing page source is the product name in upper case?

Comment: This is most likely caused by css, text-transform:uppercase in the product name styles.

Answer (score 2):

If the Product Name is "correct" in Magento Admin

Check the CSS stylesheet for something along the lines of:

```
.product-name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Or for something like:

```
echo strtoupper($product->getName());
```

in your template files.